# SUM of grouped COUNT in SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 fields:

```
ID  Name
--  -------
1   Alpha
2   Beta
3   Beta
4   Beta
5   Charlie
6   Charlie
```

I want to group them by name, with 'count', and a row 'SUM'

```
Name     Count
-------  -----
Alpha     1
Beta      3
Charlie   2
SUM       6
```

How would I write a query to add SUM row below the table?

Comment: If you need the sum in the select itself to calculate with it, use a subselect: `SELECT 
  Name,
  COUNT(*) AS amount,
  COUNT(*)/total.total * 100 AS percentage,
  total.total
FROM temp, (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM temp
) AS total
GROUP BY Name` [See SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0480d/8)

Comment: Beware in the answers below--There is no guaranteed order in a query result without ORDER BY.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS count
FROM table
GROUP BY name

UNION ALL

SELECT 'SUM' name, COUNT(name)
FROM table
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name                                               count
-------------------------------------------------- -----------
alpha                                              1
beta                                               3
Charlie                                            2
SUM                                                6
```

Comment: Valid answer. Please look at @Adriann's answer using rollup.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12927333/2012977

Comment: What is `Union all` ? EDIT : ok i was confused because of its indentation. It's juste union-ing the 2 selectors :)

Answer (score 119):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS count, SUM(COUNT(name)) OVER() AS total_count
FROM Table GROUP BY name
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: see window functions for further expl

Answer (score 20):

Without specifying which rdbms you are using

Have a look at this demo

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40708/2/0)

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(1) as Cnt
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SUM' Name, COUNT(1)
FROM Table1
```

That said, I would recomend that the total be added by your presentation layer, and not by the database.

This is a bit more of a SQL SERVER Version using [Summarizing Data Using ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40708/9/0)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (GROUPING(NAME) = 1) THEN 'SUM'
            ELSE ISNULL(NAME, 'UNKNOWN')
       END Name, 
      COUNT(1) as Cnt
FROM Table1
GROUP BY NAME
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second select be a sum, not a count?

Comment: @Greg, it should be sum if you were re-referincing the statement at the top, maybe using a WITH CTE statement ( Sql Server).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out rollup. Your answer should be the accepted answer. We have huge tables and hate hitting the table twice.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(Name,'SUM'), count(*) as Count
FROM table_name
Group By Name
WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 9):

all of the solution here are great but not necessarily can be implemented for old mysql servers (at least at my case). so you can use sub-queries (i think it is less complicated).

```
 select sum(t1.cnt) from 
        (SELECT column, COUNT(column) as cnt
            FROM
            table 
            GROUP BY 
            column
            HAVING 
            COUNT(column) > 1) as t1 ;
```

Answer (score 5):

Please run as below :

```
Select sum(count) 
  from (select Name, 
               count(Name) as Count 
          from YourTable
      group by Name);  -- 6
```

Answer (score 5):

The way I interpreted this question is needing the subtotal value of each group of answers.  Subtotaling turns out to be very easy, using `PARTITION`:

```
SUM(COUNT(0)) OVER (PARTITION BY [Grouping]) AS [MY_TOTAL]
```

This is what my full SQL call looks like:

```
SELECT MAX(GroupName) [name], MAX(AUX2)[type],  
COUNT(0) [count], SUM(COUNT(0)) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupId) AS [total]
    FROM [MyView]
  WHERE Active=1 AND Type='APP' AND Completed=1
    AND [Date] BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND GETDATE()
    AND Id = '5b9xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' AND GroupId IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY AUX2, GroupId
```

The data returned from this looks like:

```
name    type    count   total
Training Group 2    Cancelation 1   52
Training Group 2    Completed   41  52
Training Group 2    No Show 6   52
Training Group 2    Rescheduled 4   52
Training Group 3    NULL        4   10535
Training Group 3    Cancelation 857 10535
Training Group 3    Completed   7923    10535
Training Group 3    No Show 292 10535
Training Group 3    Rescheduled 1459    10535
Training Group 4    Cancelation 2   27
Training Group 4    Completed   24  27
Training Group 4    Rescheduled 1   27
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use union to joining rows.

```
select Name, count(*) as Count from yourTable group by Name
union all
select "SUM" as Name, count(*) as Count from yourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

For Sql server you can try this one.

```
SELECT ISNULL([NAME],'SUM'),Count([NAME]) AS COUNT
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY [NAME] WITH CUBE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  with cttmp
  as
  (
  select Col_Name, count(*) as ctn from tab_name group by Col_Name having count(Col_Name)>1
  )
  select sum(ctn) from c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROLLUP

```
select nvl(name, 'SUM'), count(*)
from table
group by rollup(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as

```
select Name, count(Name) as Count from YourTable
group by Name
union 
Select 'SUM' , COUNT(Name) from YourTable
```

Comment: I choose UNION ALL instead of UNION to place the 'SUM' row at the bottom (according to @VishalSuthar's answer above)

Comment: i think you misinterpret UNION and UNION ALL `UNION removes duplicate records (where all columns in the results are the same), UNION ALL does not.` thats Y i used UNION

Comment: thanks for your correction, but in this case, I must place 'SUM' on the bottom line which is can be done by using UNION ALL

Comment: do you try it with using UNION?as i have tried it must place 'SUM' at the bottom, but as far as the performance is concern UNION ALL is good in your scenario, because UNION is much less performant as it must scan the result for duplicates..

Comment: I've tried it in larger database and it place 'SUM' at around the middle of table (not always at the bottom). Anyway, I got the point of difference between UNION ALL and UNION, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using SQL server and the following should work for you:

select cast(name as varchar(16)) as 'Name', count(name) as 'Count'
  from Table1
  group by Name
  union all
  select 'Sum:', count(name)
  from Table1

Answer (score 0):

I required `having count(*) > 1` also. So, I wrote my own query after referring some the above queries

SYNTAX:

```
select sum(count) from (select count(`table_name`.`id`) as `count` from `table_name` where {some condition} group by {some_column} having count(`table_name`.`id`) > 1) as `tmp`;
```

Example:

```
select sum(count) from (select count(`table_name`.`id`) as `count` from `table_name` where `table_name`.`name` IS NOT NULL and `table_name`.`name` != '' group by `table_name`.`name` having count(`table_name`.`id`) > 1) as `tmp`;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try group by on name and count the ids in that group.

```
SELECT name, count(id) as COUNT FROM table group by name
```

Comment: I think you miss the 'SUM' row

Answer (score -2):

After the query, run below to get the total row count

```
select @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: He wants to know the count for CHARLIE for example and not the count for NAMES.

Answer (score -6):

select sum(s) from
(select count(Col_name) as s from Tab_name group by Col_name having count(*)>1)c