# Need assistance with T-SQL query UNION, JOINS, COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Looks that I am stumped with query to sum up shipments grouped by by union operator. Today I was working to retrieve total shipments (count(Distinct. U.SjipmentId) delivered by agent, driver (U.AgentCode) to particular country (U.CtryCode, U.CtryName). The last thing I would like to do is to sum all the shipments together to get the total amount of shipments. 
Would anyone advise how I this can be achieved in easy and simply way?
 Below you can find my most current query.

```
SELECT U.AgentCode, U.CtryCode, U.CtryName, count(distinct U.Id)
    FROM (
    select Agent.AgentCode, Addr.CtryCode, Ctry.Name, Ship.Id
    from Shipment
    LEFT JOIN RouteTab (nolock) ON RoutTbl.Cexp= Shipment.ID  
    LEFT JOIN Agent (NOLOCK) ON Agent.AgentID = RouteTbl.AgentID
    LEFT JOIN Addr (NOLOCK) ON Addr.AddrId = Shipment.AddrId
    LEFT JOIN Ctry (NOLOCK) ON Ctry.Id = Addr.Id
    WHERE RouteTbl.Bur ='GB01' AND Agent.AgentCode IS NOT NULL
    Union ALL
    select Driver.DriverCode, Addr.CtryCode, Ctry.Name, Shipment.Id
    from Shipment
    LEFT JOIN RouteTab (nolock) ON RoutTbl.Cexp= Shipment.Id
    LEFT JOIN Driver (NOLOCK) ON Driver.DriverId = RouteTbl.DriverId
    LEFT JOIN Addr (NOLOCK) ON Addr.AddrId = Shipment.AddrId
    LEFT JOIN Ctry (NOLOCK) ON Ctry.Id = Addr.Id
    WHERE RouteTbl.Bur ='GB01' AND Driver.DriverCode IS NOT NULL
    )  as U 
GROUP BY U.AgentCode, U.CtryCode, U.CtryName
ORDER BY U.AgentCode, U.CtryCode, U.CtryName
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of records returned by group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146978/count-number-of-records-returned-by-group-by)

Comment: Also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927268/sum-of-grouped-count-in-sql-query/12927333#12927333

Answer (score 0):

Union statements need to have the exact same column names, in your code below the Union All command, try this:

```
select Driver.DriverCode as AgentCode, Addr.CtryCode, Ctry.Name, Shipment.Id
```

Also change the `Ctry.Name` to `Ctry.Name as CtryName` in both your select statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same code from your `UNION`. Good way to use `WITH` clause.
In your `select` you don't need a `UNION` - use a left join and `COALESCE` instead.

```
;With r_tab AS
(
select RouteTab.AgentID, Addr.CtryCode, Ctry.Name, Ship.Id,RouteTab.DriverId
    from Shipment
    LEFT JOIN RouteTab (nolock) ON RouteTab.Cexp= Shipment.ID 
    LEFT JOIN Addr (NOLOCK) ON Addr.AddrId = Shipment.AddrId
    LEFT JOIN Ctry (NOLOCK) ON Ctry.Id = Addr.Id
    WHERE RouteTab.Bur ='GB01'
)
SELECT COALESCE(Agent.AgentCode,Driver.DriverCode) AgentCode, U.AgentCode, U.CtryCode, U.CtryName,
       count(distinct U.Id)
    FROM r_tab U
    LEFT JOIN Agent (NOLOCK) ON Agent.AgentID = U.AgentID
       AND Agent.AgentCode IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN Driver (NOLOCK) ON Driver.DriverId = U.DriverId
       AND Driver.DriverCode IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY COALESCE(Agent.AgentCode,Driver.DriverCode), U.CtryCode, U.CtryName
ORDER BY U.AgentCode, U.CtryCode, U.CtryName`enter code here`
```