# Sum of item count in an SQL query based on DATE_TRUNC

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sum

I've got a table which contains event status data, similar to this:

```
  ID             Time               Status
------  --------------------------  ------
357920  2019-12-25 09:31:38.854764    1
362247  2020-01-02 09:31:42.498483    1
362248  2020-01-02 09:31:46.166916    1
362249  2020-01-02 09:31:47.430933    1
362300  2020-01-03 09:31:46.932333    1
362301  2020-01-03 09:31:47.231288    1
```

I'd like to construct a query which returns the number of successful events each day, so:

```
         Time              Count
-------------------------- -----
2019-12-25 00:00:00.000000   1
2020-01-02 00:00:00.000000   3
2020-01-03 00:00:00.000000   2
```

I've stumbled across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12927334/14302) to a similar question, but the answer there is for all the data returned by the query, whereas I need the sum grouped by date range.

Also, I *cannot* use `BETWEEN` to select a specific date range, since this query is for a Grafana dashboard, and the date range is determined by the dashboard's UI. I'm using Postgres for the SQL dialect, in case that matters.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Since the question is about SQL and not related specifically to Postgres, I decided *not* to tag the question with this. But sure, you may have a good point, so I'll add this tag. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the time from `time` component.  In most databases, you can do this by converting to a `date`:

```
select cast(time as date) as dte, 
       sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_successful
from t
group by cast(time as date)
order by dte;
```

This assumes that `1` means "successful".

The `cast()` does not work in all databases.  Other alternatives are things like `trunc(time)`, `date_trunc('day', time)`, `date_trunc(time, day)` -- and no doubt many others.

In Postgres, I would phrase this as:

```
select date_trunc('day', time) as dte, 
       count(*) filter (where status = 1) as num_successful
from t
group by dte
order by dte;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```
SELECT date(Time), sum(status) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY date(Time)
ORDER BY min(Time)
```